# Why is a NoClassDefFoundError being caused even after IMporting external JAR

Tags: java, api

I am having a problem with the Yahoo Finance API in Java (Using Eclipse). I am getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` when I compile my code, when I remove all the yahoo stuff the code compiles perfectly. The method I used to add the JARs is to go to Properties -> Libraries -> Add External JARS and then I added YahooFinanceAPI-3.14.0.jar. Than I went to the build path and checked it there.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at yahoofinance.quotes.query1v7.QuotesRequest.<clinit>(QuotesRequest.java:28)
at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.getQuotes(YahooFinance.java:380)
at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.get(YahooFinance.java:98)
at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.get(YahooFinance.java:82)
at Main.main(Main.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 5 more
```

Comment: You need to add slf4j lib in your context as external jar. Use https://mvnrepository.com to find jar files you need.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency on Yahoo finance has transitive dependencies that are not included in the jar you added to your build path, thus the error your are seeing, which leaves you with two choices:

1. Track the missing dependencies one by one and find the jars required and add them to your build path
2. use some kind of dependency management too like `maven` or `gradle` to resolve those dependencies for you .